# Unit test a DAO

Tags: java, testing, dao, easymock

I've been trying to do a unit test of my DAO but I haven't find out the way to do it yet and I'm feeling a little desperate. I have a tiny DAO that looks like this:

```
public interface ElectionsDao {
    List<String> getDates();
}
```

I'm using Spring framework to do DI using `SimpleJdbcTemplate`. My implementation looks like this:

```
public class ElectionsDaoImpl extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport implements ElectionsDao {
    public List<String> getDates() {
        List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            dates = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query("SELECT electiondate FROM electiondate", new StringRowMapper());
        } catch (DataAccessException ex){
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        return dates;
    }

    protected static final class StringRowMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<String> {
        public String mapRow(ResultSet rs, int line) throws SQLException {
            String string = new String(rs.getString("electiondate"));
            return string;
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is just a unit test of `getDates()` using EasyMock but I haven't found the way to do it. I'm so confused. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: You'll need to use the latest EasyMock that supports class extension to override the behavior of `getSimpleJdbcTemplate()` to return a mock object of `SimpleJdbcTemplate` with a behavior defined for `query`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though `getSimpleJdbcTemplate` is the biggest problem for unit testing. One way you could test is to extend the class under test and override the `getSimpleJdbcTemplate` method e.g.

```
public class ElectionDaoTest {

    /** Class under test */
    private ElectionsDaoImpl dao;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        dao = new ElectionsDaoImpl(){
            SimpleJdbcTemplate getSimpleJdbcTemplate(){
                // Return easy mock version here.
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    // Do tests
}
```

There may be an easier way with EasyMock, but I'm not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your comments. I decided to do the test using Spring. My test code ended like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:beans.xml")
public class DBConectionTest{

    @Resource
    private ElectionsDao electionsDao;

    @Test
    public void testGetDates(){
        List<String> dates = electionsDao.getDates();
        assertNotNull(dates);
    }
}
```

I'm using the same xml file that I use when running my project. Hope it helps someone.